# Invalid initializer member class with enum

Tags: c#, class, enums

I have a class and enum,how can I initilize like this way, my initializer,

```
SkSqlPamameter prm = new SkSqlPamameter 
    { 
        ParameterName = "@param1", 
        Value = "param1", SkSqlDbType.Int 
    };
```

and class and enum;

```
 enum SkSqlDbType
    {
        Int,
        Nvarchar,
        Date,
        Bool,
        Decimal,
        Double
    }
    public class  SkSqlPamameter  
    {         
        public string ParameterName;
        public SkSqlDbType SkDbType;
        public string Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SkSqlPamameter prm = new SkSqlPamameter 
 { 
    ParameterName = "@param1", 
    Value = "param1", 
    SkDbType = SkSqlDbType.Int // you missed property name here
 };
```

Object initializer contains member initializers, which should look like *identifier = initializer-value*. From C# specification 7.6.10.2 Object initializers:

> Each member initializer must name an accessible field or property of
>   the object being initialized, followed by an equals sign and an
>   expression or an object initializer or collection initializer.